# Partial differential equation with variable coefficients

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am stuck with the following problem.

I know how to solve the following partial differential equation
$$\frac{\partial u(x,t)}{\partial t} +A(x,t)  \frac{\partial^2 u(x,t)}{\partial^2 x}+ B(x,t) \frac{\partial u(x,t)}{\partial x} - Cu(x,t)=0,$$
if $A(x,t)=A$ and $B(x,t)=B$ are constants for all $(x,t)$ and I have some boundary conditions (note that $C$ is also a constant).

However, what if $A$ and $B$ are variable (i.e. they are functions of $x$ and $t$)? What is then the correct approach to solve this PDE with variable coefficients?

Comment: Explicitly or numerically? You need boundary/initial conditions.

Comment: Explicitly. Is it not possible to find the general solution without having an explicit boundary solution?